# Multicast android ios cross platform

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, react-native, multicast

Right now I have an app in android, which multicasts to android on the local network, but the code is written in Java. So how can I multicast cross platform?

- Is there a lib for Multicasting cross platform?
- should I use react native?
- should I use some webrtc parts or another cross platform sip vendor (ie. pjsip)?

Comment: You should define a protocol for multicasting, and handle the types correctly in Objective C/ Swift and Java, how is the multicast made? Using sockets? If you use sockets, then it doesn't really matter the language as long as you implement the defined protocol and correctly handle the language types, if you use a sort of library or something, would be useful to know the name f it

Comment: your iOS app then should contain them as well, as I said if its a socket based communication, it should work, as long as you implement the protocol correctly

Comment: the Android app contains both Server and Client. All in Java, no specific lib
Server is  Datagram Socket + UDP DatagramPaket to IP 224.0.0.3 Port 8888
Client is MulticastSocket joined to group  to same IP:port . 

And you mean then I send UDP to 224.0.0.3:8888 from Java/Android App (as Server) the iOS will get this Messages even in Objective C? thx

Comment: yes, you can use sockets in objective c as well and it should work